# Javascript: Insert new level in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Okay, I have:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="mydiv">
   <p>Text</p>
   ... Here is something more inside ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to have:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="newdiv">
    <div id="mydiv">
      <p>Text</p>
      ... Here is something more inside ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how can I take everyting inside "container" and insert a new div "newdiv" which gets the childs from "container" as childs using JavaScript? Using jquery is an option.

Answer (score 1):

use `.wrap()`:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).wrap( "<div class='newdiv'></div>" );
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2w483/)**

Answer (score 1):

using [`wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$('#mydiv').wrap($('<div>').attr('id','newDiv'));
```

Demo `---->`  http://jsfiddle.net/FCfP9/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.wrap()](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)**:

> Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched
>   elements.

```
$("#mydiv").wrap("<div id='newdiv'></div>" );
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65AtY/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container').contents().wrapAll('<div id="newdiv"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can use pure js:

```
var content = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
var newHtml = "<div id='newDiv'>" + content + "</div>";
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = newHtml;
```

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hWc95/

Comment: +1 easy to do with native javascript. But I'm using appendchild on a new div instead of plain text.

Comment: In this case - yes, `appendChild` would be better. Because we are just _appending_. If we want to replace DOM, we need to use `innerHtml`.